# In TeamCity, is there a system/environment variable for the current build id?

Tags: configuration, teamcity

In TeamCity build configuration we have access to all kinds of properties of the build via the %propertyname% syntax.  For example, %env.BUILD_NUMBER%.

But one seems to be missing, and that is a property for the current *build id*.  That is, the unique identifier assigned to every build.  It's what the [TeamCity REST api](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin) calls the "internal build id".  Not to be confused with the BUILD_NUMBER (which is more like a label), nor the "build type id" (which is the unique id assigned to the build configuration).

Answer (score 4):

This is available as %teamcity.build.id%, at least in version 6, I haven't tried earlier versions.